# How to get a list of active notifications prior API 23

Tags: android, android-notifications

The code snapets below fetches active notifications but it require API 23+ where my code running 21+

Knowing that my requirement is simple, I just want to find out the apps packages that has active notifications, I don't want to read the notifications data, I don't want to cancel them.

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    StatusBarNotification[] n = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();

    for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        n[i].getPackageName();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NotificationListenerService` which has `getActiveNotifications()` method!

Comment: Thank you :) but how to call getActiveNotifications() from my Activity?

Comment: @Jack create a public static ArrayList in service, add all active notifs in that list, get that ArrayList in Activity! don't forget to clear the ArrayList in Activity's onDestroy!

Comment: Thank you :) I used service Binder which gives me access to an instance of the service where I can call getActiveNotifications()

Comment: This is overkill and really limited in latest API versions